# How do I return true or false for ternary operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, return, conditional-operator

I'm trying to convert the code below to a shorthand version with a ternary operator

```
     if (sum % 10 === 0) {
        return true;
     } else {
        return false;
      }
```

It works fine as is, but when I change it to

```
sum % 10 === 0 ? return true : return false;
```

I get a syntax error, and when I change it to

```
sum % 10 === 0 ? true : false;
```

it doesn't work as intended.

If anyone can enlighten me as to what's going on, I'd be much appreciated.

Comment: ```return sum % 10 === 0 ? true : false; ```

Comment: Even `return sum % 10 === 0` should be fine

Comment: `return sun % 10 === 0;`   If the condition is true, will return true, if the condition is false, will return false.

Comment: _"If anyone can enlighten me..."_ -> [Conditional (ternary) operator - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried:

```
sum % 10 === 0 ? return true : return false;
```

This does not work, because [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) is a statement and not an expression. A statement can not be used inside of an expression.

```
sum % 10 === 0 ? true : false;
```

This works, but without a `return` statement, it is just an expression without using it.

Finally, you need to retur the result of the [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), like

```
return sum % 10 === 0 ? true : false;
```

For a shorter approach you could return the result of the comparison without ternary.

```
return sum % 10 === 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

The expression `(sum % 10 === 0)` is boolean itself, so just return it:

```
return sum % 10 === 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do:

```
return !(sum % 10)
```

if `(sum % 10) === 0`, then `!(sum % 10)` will return `true`, else `false`.